# rails SyntaxError unexpected in, expecting then or ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Error description is

```
SyntaxError: /workspace/SiUber/app/views/siuber/search.html.erb:128: syntax error, unexpected in, expecting then or ';' or '\n'
    if @se in ss.title
           ^~/workspace/SiUber/app/views/siuber/search.html.erb:139: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
      end
      ^~~
  '`<%
@search.each do |ss| 
    if @se in ss.title
        %>
        <hr>
        <h6><a href='<%= ss.link %>'><%= ss.title %></a></h6>
        <p>
            올린사람 : <%= ss.maker %>
        </p>
        <hr>
    <% end
end %>`
```

Comment: Format your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume @se is an array

so please try the below code

```
<% @search.each do |ss|  %>
  <% if @se.include?(ss.title) %>
    <hr>
    <h6><a href='<%= ss.link %>'><%= ss.title %></a></h6>
    <p> 올린사람 : <%= ss.maker %> </p>
    <hr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

if it's not working then please add complete code here.